# Does a 1-byte UTF-8 "sequence" have a special name?

Tags: utf-8

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Description), in UTF-8, the first byte in a multi-byte sequence is called a *leading byte*, and the subsequent bytes in the sequence are called *continuation byte*.

I understand these might not be the "official" names (in fact, the [UTF-8 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#page-4) does not provide any names for the different octet types), but according to Wikipedia and based on my research so far, these seem to be the names in common use.

Is there a special name in common use for a byte that is neither a leading byte nor a continuation byte (i.e., for code points < 128)?

I'm documenting some fairly complex code that is designed to work with UTF-8-encoded strings, and I'd like to make sure to use standard terminology to avoid confusion.

Comment: The UTF-8 RFCs don't even use the names *leading byte* or *continuation byte*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everywhere I would expect to see a definition, I cannot find a special term for this (beyond the already mentioned ASCII). The only thing I can add is that a one-byte "sequence" is a legitimate sequence and that the one byte is *not* excluded from being called a leading byte.

References from the Unicode standard:

- [§3.9 (PDF, pg. 119)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch03.pdf)

  > A code unit sequence may consist of a single code unit.
- [§2.5 (PDF, pg. 37)](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch02.pdf)

  > A range of 8-bit code unit values is reserved for the first, or *leading*, element of a UTF-8 code unit sequences, and a completely disjunct range of 8-bit code unit values is reserved for the subsequent, or *trailing*, elements of such sequences;

Answer (score 2):

Some would refer to first 7bits of UTF-8 as **ASCII**.

Comment: How does this answer the question? What would you call a one-byte sequence? An "ASCII byte"? An "ASCII sequence"? Is this supposed to be standard terminology?

Comment: A one-byte sequence is an oxymoron, unless you're referring to the bits, but I'm happy to let that pass. An ASCII character is the common, unofficial term for a byte in the first 7 bits of UTF-8. That answers the question.